# using Deep Learning VM without GPU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-compute-engine, google-dl-platform

I'm trying to learn how to do ML/PyTorch on Google Cloud.  The [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/cloud-partners/) recommend the [Deep Learning VM](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning), but I have a GPU quota of 0, and even if my quota allowed it, I don't really want to spend $300/month just to go through some PyTorch tutorials.

How can I configure this VM for CPU only?  Or is there another, similar "click to deploy" PyTorch setup that does not require a GPU?

Comment: Pytorch does not require a GPU. The libraries auto-detect available CPU features and GPUs. I am not aware of `click to deploy` products and features as I do not use them. Installing and setting up Pytorch applications is easy and there are documents and tutorials to learn from.

Comment: Correct.  That's why I know I *ought* to be able to use this VM, but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: The comment `I just can't figure out how` is not a problem description. Explain what you are doing and the error messages.

Comment: There are no error messages.  I'm looking for a way to change the configuration so that it does not require a GPU, and I do not see how to do this.  If there is a button or widget that can be manipulated to so change the configuration I can't find it.  I don't know how to say "I can't figure it out" any more explicitly.

I suspect this would make sense to you if you had ever tried the `click to deploy` products, but as you haven't, perhaps you should ignore this question and leave it to those who have.

Comment: Well, perhaps I _can_ be more specific: the "GPU type" pop-up has options of Tesla P100, T4, or V100, but there is no "none" option.  And the "Number of GPUs" lets me pick 1, 2, or 4; there is no "0" option.  So I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you can accomplish your task:

1. Use `Vertex AI` preconfigured VMs
   Go to Workbench - Enable API - New Instance - User Managed - PyTorch
   They are cheap and come with all libraries needed. You don't need to add GPUs.
2. Use `Google Cloud Skills Boost`
   You can also pay a monthly fee of 29 USD to have access to many LABs using Vertex AI. But you will have to find PyTorch LABs.
3. You can go to `Compute Engine` and create a new VM, changing the image of the VM to a Deep Learning one. You will need to SSH and also install Jupyter.

For all of them, the cost will depend upon the number of cores you choose. For me, Vertex AI is more adequate, as you already have Jupyter notebooks installed and does not need to SSH, as it has JupyterLab.

Note: N1 instances are the cheapest.

Comment: I tried to follow suggestion 3, but I don't see how to do that.  When I create a new VM, if I choose "New VM instance from machine image," it tells me that I don't have any machine images.  I'll now go see if I can figure out option 1, but can you elaborate on how I would do suggestion 3?

Comment: OK, now trying suggestion 1, I was able to find and enable the "Vertex AI" API, and apparently I don't need to create credentials.  I don't see any "New Instance" there however.  So I went to Compute Engine -> New VM Instance, but here I don't see any "User Managed" option.  Can you please explain where/how I set up a Vertex AI instance?

Comment: Huh.  By exiting my Google Cloud page entirely and just doing some searching, I was able to find https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai, which looks completely different from where I was before.  Though now I see it's accessible from the main Cloud menu if you expose "additional services" and scroll down to the "Artificial Intelligence" section at the bottom.

Comment: Marking this the accepted answer — it technically didn't answer how to do get Deep Learning VM to work without a GPU (perhaps that's impossible), but it correctly identified and satisfied the underlying need, which was to have an easy, ready-to-use ML setup in Google Cloud.  Vertex AI seems to do that nicely.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Select a VM that uses CPUs

[image]

To remove this warning

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud provide an Operating System which is called [Deep Learning VM images](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/images) (An image refers to the Google Cloud concept of an Operating system).
This Operating system pre-installs TensorFlow, Pytorch, etc.

You create a VM with your desired machine type, GPU, disks or network configuration you need, this is independent of the OS you select.

You are mixing up Hardware and Software concepts.

You can create a Deep Learning VM using Google Cloud Compute API or you can create a VM by using (Vertex) which uses Notebooks API. Both use the same underlying OS.

https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/